# flowtype typeof class does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Below code does not typecheck.
THe error says:

"Cannot assign `new YourClass()` to `test1` because `YourClass` [1] is incompatible with class `YourClass` [2]."

```
/* @flow */

class YourClass {
  method(){}
}

let test1: typeof YourClass = new YourClass();
```

What exactly does `typeof SomeClass` infer to?

Can someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeof YourClass` is the type of the constructor function itself, so the following typechecks:

```
let test1: typeof YourClass = YourClass;
```

this can be useful if you needed to pass a constructor around and your class has subclasses, e.g.

```
class Subclass extends YourClass {}

let test1: typeof YourClass = Subclass;
```